# How to generate a Curve25519 key pair in Terminal?

Tags: public-key-encryption, command-line-tool, curve-25519

How can we generate a Curve25519 key pair from the command line?

We have a MacBook Air with Homebrew installed.

1. Should we use OpenSSL or another command line tool?
2. How do we use that tool to generate a Curve25519 key pair?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the following command for generating the key pair:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm x25519 -out x25519-priv.pem
```

And for extracting public key:

```
openssl pkey -in x25519-priv.pem -pubout -out x25519-pub.pem
```

Answer (score 1):

openssl in MacOS is apples own openssl that does not support Curve25519
you need to install it with brew

```sh
brew install openssl
```

and then link using PATH or using `brew link --force openssl`(not recommended) for example if you are using zsh

```sh
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

to check. if it worked just use the `which` command

```sh
which openssl
```

now if you see output like this you are good to go 
`/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/openssl`
now you can generate Curve25519 keys with using openssl

```sh
openssl genpkey -algorithm x25519 -out x25519-priv.pem
```